# Dialogflow V2 Agent Versioning on Java Client

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I'm porting to DialogFlow V2 and would like to give agent-versions a try. Read about it here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-versions

The thing is that I don't know how that affects the configuration on credentials, as I wan't able to find anything on the client library. The current code I have for authentication is

```
  public DialogFlowEngine(DialogFlowConfig config) throws IOException {
    this.config = config;
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getClientCredentials().getBytes())
    );
    this.sessionSettings =
        SessionsSettings.newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
            .build();
    this.projectId = ((ServiceAccountCredentials)credentials).getProjectId();
  }
```

Then when creating the session:

```
try (SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(this.sessionSettings)) {
        SessionName session = SessionName.of(projectId, requestId);
    ...
```

I've seen that if I wanted to use the agent-versioning feature using the RAW rest endpoint I'd have to post to a url like `"https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/small-talk-dfghk/agent/environments/development/users/-/sessions/e5472b8a-9feb-43f1-8213-648215960d22:detectIntent"`

However by the looks of the api it seems that such operation can't be performed as he SessionName class decompiled matches a URL like so:

```
private static final PathTemplate PATH_TEMPLATE = PathTemplate.createWithoutUrlEncoding("projects/{project}/agent/sessions/{session}");
```

Is there a way we could do it? How would you recommend configuring DialogFlow between environments (dev, qa, staging, prod...) otherwise?

Even if I had the proper API call I still wonder... Do different agent versions mean we can have different Json credentials per environment?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SessionName.ofProjectEnvironmentUserSessionName` and it receives the environment name just as the REST api does.